Fail to swap USDT to WETH in curve pool
I want to swap my USDT to WETH in curve pool: [USDT, wBTC, WETH].
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity =0.8.10;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract ContractTest is Test {
    address pool = 0xD51a44d3FaE010294C616388b506AcdA1bfAAE46; // curve pool: USDT-wBTC-WETH
    address usdt = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7;
    IWETH WETH = IWETH(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2);

    function setUp() public {
        vm.createSelectFork("mainnet", 14_684_306);
    }

    function test_swap() public {
        deal(address(usdt), address(this), 123456789);

        IUSDT(usdt).approve(pool, type(uint256).max);
        uint256 allowance = IERC20(usdt).allowance(address(this), pool);
        console.log("allowance", allowance);

        console.log("Before swap, USDT balance:", IUSDT(usdt).balanceOf(address(this)));
        // USDT => WETH
        ICurve(pool).exchange(0, 2, IUSDT(usdt).balanceOf(address(this)), 0);
        console.log("After swap, USDT balance :", IUSDT(usdt).balanceOf(address(this)));
        console.log("WETH", WETH.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
}


interface IUSDT {
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external;
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256);
}

interface ICurve {
    function exchange(int128 i, int128 j, uint256 dx, uint256 min_dy) external;
}

interface IWETH {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256);
    function deposit() external payable;
}

But the result is that: the tx is not revert, but I can not swap successfully. The [1676] 0xD51a44d3FaE010294C616388b506AcdA1bfAAE46::exchange(0, 2, 2048023898827 [2.048e12], 0) does nothing:
    ├─ [0] console::log("allowance", 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1031] 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7::balanceOf(ContractTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 123456789 [1.234e8]
    ├─ [0] console::log("Before swap, USDT balance:", 123456789 [1.234e8]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1031] 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7::balanceOf(ContractTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 123456789 [1.234e8]
    ├─ [1676] 0xD51a44d3FaE010294C616388b506AcdA1bfAAE46::exchange(0, 2, 123456789 [1.234e8], 0)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1031] 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7::balanceOf(ContractTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 123456789 [1.234e8]
    ├─ [0] console::log("After swap, USDT balance :", 123456789 [1.234e8]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [2534] 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2::balanceOf(ContractTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] console::log("WETH", 0) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()

the log:
Logs:
  allowance 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
  Before swap, USDT balance: 123456789
  After swap, USDT balance : 123456789
  WETH 0

I have tried different EVM version: shanghai, cancun, london, berlin and so on, but it does not work.

Resolve the problem by changing the interface.
interface ICurve {
    function exchange(uint256 i, uint256 j, uint256 dx, uint256 min_dy) external;
}

Reason for error: ABI error. This error was caused by personal carelessness. Not all pools have the same ABI, so it is necessary to check the interface carefully when using it.
